# How to place Windows Forms objects/tools using a ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Well I didn't really know how to phrase the question, but here is what I mean:

I am making a C# application on Windows Visual Studio. Users can select an item from the ListBox on the lefthand side of the form, and the appropriate information is displayed on the right hand side. Each item from the ListBox will display a different combination of images, buttons, labels, etc on the right hand side.

When using the designer for Windows Form, each object (button, label) is shown, making it difficult to place different objects for each item on the ListBox.I am getting to the point where there is so many buttons, labels, etc. overlayed of each other that I cannot properly place my items.

How can I solve this? Should I be using some sort of control?

Edit: Heres an example of what I am currently doing:

```
 if ((string)choiceBox.SelectedItem == "Home")
        {
            thatLabel.Visible = true;
            someLabel.Visible = true;
            anotherLogo.Visible = true;
            madeLabel.Visible = true;

            basiclabel3.Visible = false;
            basiclabel2.Visible = false;
            basiclabel1.Visible = false;
            externalipLabel.Visible = false;
            ipLabel.Visible = false;
            computernameLabel.Visible = false;
        }
        else if ((string)choiceBox.SelectedItem == "Basic Details")
        {
            string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            string ip = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();


            string extIP;
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                extIP = wc.DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com/");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extIP))
            {
                externalipLabel.Text = extIP.ToString();
                externalipLabel.Visible = true;
            }   
            ipLabel.Text = ip.ToString();
            ipLabel.Visible = true;
            computernameLabel.Text = hostName.ToString();
            computernameLabel.Visible = true;
            basiclabel1.Visible = true;
            basiclabel2.Visible = true;
            basiclabel3.Visible = true;

            thatLabel.Visible = false;
            someLabel.Visible = false;
            anotherLabel.Visible = false;
            madeLabel.Visible = false;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: What about making custom controls for each possible choice and showing /creating the appropriate control dynamically?

Comment: @EugenePodskal thats what im trying to do.

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you know how to create custom controls? Do you know how to show/create controls dynamically? If not - those question are already asked at least few times, so can be easily searched and applied to solve your issue.

Comment: @EugenePodskal see my updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make custom controls in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405458/how-do-i-make-custom-controls-in-c)

Comment: @EugenePodskal forget it, I'll just use multiple forms.

Comment: @levijoraan you use MVVM and databinding+data templates+contentpresenter in WPF and this is a piece of cake.  On the left hand side a ListBox, on the right-hand side a ContentPresenter with Content bound to SelectedItem in your viewmodel.