# Get AddressOf from MethodInfo object

Tags: vb.net

I have labels that I created programmatically and want to give specific event handlers to each one. So, Instead of doing this:

```
AddHandler Label1.Click, AddressOf SomeSub1
AddHandler Label2.Click, AddressOf SomeSub2
AddHandler Label3.Click, AddressOf SomeSub3
...
```

I was hoping to work it into a loop to avoid the above. So I made:

- A List of Labels
- A MethodInfo array of all my already built, Private Subs in a class that is inherits from the main class where the labels are

I used the above and came up with the following:

```
Dim separateClass As New SeparateClass
Dim methodInfo() As MethodInfo = separateClass.GetType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)

For i As Integer = 0 to End
    labelList.Add(New Label())
    AddHandler labelList.Last.Click, AddressOf [Delegate].CreateDelegate(GetType(SomeDelegate), separateClass, methodInfo(i)).GetMethodInfo
Next
```

And this does compile but the Subs aren't being triggered. The following also compiles but behaves the same way:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to End
    labelList.Add(New Label())
    AddHandler labelList.Last.Click, AddressOf methodInfo(i).getBaseDefinition
Next
```

Is there a way I can get the appropriate `AddressOf` out of a `MethodInfo` object?

Comment: might be easier to make a custom control and override the onClick event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405458/how-do-i-make-custom-controls-in-c

Comment: You are registering the Click event on `New Label()`, not the labels you are using on your form.  The `New` keyword is descriptive here.  So sure, that doesn't work, those labels are not even visible.

Comment: I cut out a lot of extra stuff I do to add these to my MainForm. They're added, given text, font, size, and all that stuff somewhere else. I just didn't do it here so that only the portion I'm having trouble with can be focused on. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Delegate].CreateDelegate` already creates a delegate object; you should not use `AddressOf`.

You may need to cast it, though.

Comment: Man... am I bad at this. I created an EventDelegate when there's already the built in one called EventHandler -.- I made the change you suggested and this totally fixed it. Thanks.