# C# - How to set Default properties of Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm coding (and designing) for speed for a mini-competition using Windows Forms and I find myself repetitively changing a few design properties every time I create a new form. Some of these properties are:

- StartPosition
- Size
- FormBorderStyle
- MaximizeBox

My question is: Is there any way I can specify my default settings on each form I create?

Comment: Create your own controls.

Comment: Well google didn't think its vague ;)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6405473/3956100

Comment: Im sorry if i dont seem helpful im merely trying to help. Also i searched how to create my own controls.. im trying to tell you this to show you that doing this for all your controls in your project is good. Because if after 6 months you decide to change the font on lets say all your textboxes, and you have used your own controls in your 1000 forms, then all you have to do is write 1 line of code in your control class...

Comment: @Niklas No issue. I was more concerned about my form properties rather than custom controls however, so I didn't know what exactly the term is in order to search on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Base Form and set your default properties in the constructor. Once you added new Form, go to the code file, change the Form inherited from the `BaseForm` you created. That's it !!

BaseForm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOF
{
    public class BaseForm : Form
    {
        public BaseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Size = new Size(400, 400);
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
        }
    }
}
```

FormInherited.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOF
{
    public partial class FormInherited : BaseForm
    {
        public FormInherited()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand a little on what you are saying. Could you provide a code sample/example for reference? As in, Where is this `BaseForm` class?

Comment: `Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'BaseForm' is less accessible than class 'TestForm'` Why is that so?

Comment: I think your base class doesn't have `public` as I provided. Can you check this?

Comment: Yup you're definitely right. I forgot to put in that one. But the problem now is that I can not access my Designer for 'TestForm' after inheriting from the `BaseForm`.

Comment: @Kuyo Let me check

Comment: I figured out the issue. The solution is to create a Form for `BaseForm` instead of a Class. I've picked you as the correct answer :) Could you update your answer?

Comment: @Kuyo sure, will do :-)