# Set background color of button depending on percentage

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, button, background-color

In c#, windows forms, I would like to change button background color depending on the input double value which is between 1 and 100. For example

- If percentage is 100 whole button color should be yellow.
- If e.g. 75%, then 75% of the button should be yellow and 25% blue, horizontally, meaning left part of the 25% of the button in blue and right part of the button in yellow.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the issue. I want part of the button to be in one color and part of the button in other color, depending on the input value. If input value is e.g. 20, i want left 20% of the button to be in one color and remaining part in other color. Input can be any number between 1 and 100.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom button control and use its BackgroundImage to draw the progress. This way you can keep the look and feel of the button (including the visual style). All the painting logic will be in the control and the application code will be like this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    percentButton1.Percent = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    percentButton1.Text = $"{ percentButton1.Percent}%";
}
```

And this is the result that you see:

[image]

In the following example, I've created 3 properties for the PercentButton:

- Percent
- PercentCompletedColor
- PercentRemainingColor

Here is the code:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class PercentButton : Button
{
    public PercentButton()
    {
        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    }

    Color percentCompletedColor = Color.Yellow;
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Yellow")]
    public Color PercentCompletedColor
    {
        get { return percentCompletedColor; }
        set
        {
            if (percentCompletedColor != value)
            {
                percentCompletedColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    Color percentRemainingColor = Color.Blue;
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Blue")]
    public Color PercentRemainingColor
    {
        get { return percentRemainingColor; }
        set
        {
            if (percentRemainingColor != value)
            {
                percentCompletedColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private int percent = 50;
    [DefaultValue(50)]
    public int Percent
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0) value = 0;
            if (value > 100) value = 100;
            if (percent != value)
            {
                percent = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override Image BackgroundImage
    {
        get { return base.BackgroundImage; }
        set { base.BackgroundImage = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override ImageLayout BackgroundImageLayout
    {
        get { return base.BackgroundImageLayout; }
        set { base.BackgroundImageLayout = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        if (BackgroundImage == null)
            BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(100, 10);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(BackgroundImage))
        {
            if (Percent > 0)
                using (var b1 = new SolidBrush(PercentCompletedColor))
                    g.FillRectangle(b1, new Rectangle(0, 0, Percent, 10));
            if (Percent < 100)
                using (var b1 = new SolidBrush(PercentRemainingColor))
                    g.FillRectangle(b1, new Rectangle(Percent, 0, Percent, 10));
        }
        base.OnPaint(pevent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great.  Only suggestion would be to protect against unnecessary calls to `Invalidate` by checking if `value` equals what is already assigned.  Such as `set { if (value != percentRemainingColor) { percentRemainingColor = value; Invalidate(); } }`, etc.  This is probably most important for the `Percent` property.  As written I could assign it the same value over and over and `Invalidate` will be called.

Comment: @Idle_Mind The background image is Stretch.(The easiest way to get rid of any of calculation, at the same time, keep look and feel of the button.)

Comment: @Zer0, true, I [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879068/3110834) care about it.

Comment: Stretch...I totally missed that!

Comment: @Nenad Birešev Does this answer your question? Let me know if you have any problem in applying the answet :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not have a button with two colors at the same time with BackgroundColor propertis.
First you must create a Component button And do it custom.
right click>add new item >select CustomControl from windows form>Enter Name>OK

After that, it is enough to edit the code. The class inherits from the button class instead of the control class

```
 public partial class TwoColorButton : Button
    {

        Color clr1, clr2;
        private Color color1 = Color.DodgerBlue;
        private Color color2 = Color.MidnightBlue;
        private int angle = 90;
        private int textX = 100;
        private int textY = 25;
        private String text = "";


        public int ButtonAngle
        {
            get { return angle; }
            set { angle = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public String ButtonText
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { text = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color StartColor
        {
            get { return color1; }
            set { color1 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public Color EndColor
        {
            get { return color2; }
            set { color2 = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        

        public int GradientAngle
        {
            get { return angle; }
            set { angle = value; Invalidate(); }
        }

        public int TextLocation_X
        {
            get { return textX; }
            set { textX = value; Invalidate(); }
        }
        public int TextLocation_Y
        {
            get { return textY; }
            set { textY = value; Invalidate(); }
        }      
        public TwoColorButton()
        {
            this.Size = new Size(100, 40);
            this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            this.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            this.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = Color.Transparent;
            text = this.Text;
        }

       
        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            color1 = clr1;
            color2 = clr2;
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnResize(e);
            textX = (int)((this.Width / 3) - 1);
            textY = (int)((this.Height / 3) + 5);
        }


        //draw circular button function  
       
        //draw rectangular button function  
        void DrawRectangularButton(Graphics g)
        {
            Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(250, color1);
            Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(250, color2);


            Brush b = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, c1, c2, angle);
            g.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);


            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220))), this.Width - i, 0, this.Width - i, this.Height);
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220))), 0, this.Height - i, this.Width, this.Height - i);

                g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220))), 0 + i, 0, 0 + i, this.Height);
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(220, 220, 220))), 0, 0 + i, this.Width, i);
            }           
                Point p = new Point(textX, textY);
                SolidBrush frcolor = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);
                g.DrawString(text, this.Font, frcolor, p);           

            b.Dispose();
        }




        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            this.DrawRectangularButton(e.Graphics);            
        }



    }
```

[image]

[More read about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405458/how-do-i-make-custom-controls-in-c)